# Google maps setPaths from getPaths coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to get the Paths of a polygon, and then set them to another polygon like that.

```
newpoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths:poly.getPaths()
            });
```

Isn't this suppose to work ? It gives me this error in the console.

**Invalid value for constructor parameter 0: [object Object]**

Comment: Can you show a little more code where you have initialized your poly variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following before you instantiate the polygon object

```
var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
  ];
```

Now use you code and replace the poly.getPaths() - Assuming the rest of your code works.

```
newpoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths:triangleCoords //there are probably more method to add here 
            });
```

If it works then you know there is something wrong with poly.getPaths(). Use this as reference https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolygonOptions.

Remember that we can only use the code that was provide to formulate an solution.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you can show the code for poly object and if poly.getPaths() return anything. All I can recomand si to debug it in detail like this:

1. Do you hace any error if you comment paths:poly:Paths();
2. Console.log(poly); return a google map polygon?
3. Console.log(poly.getPaths()) return an array of paths?
4. If yes, you can try to create an array from poly.getPaths then pass it to newpoly.

Answer (score 0):

Get the coords of first polygon this way (assuming that the two polygons were already created):

```
           //store polygon path
            var vertices = firstPolygon.getPath();
            // Iterate over the vertices.
            pathOfFirstPolygon = [];
            for (var i =0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
                var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
                item = {};
                item["lat"] = xy.lat();
                item["lng"] = xy.lng();
                pathOfFirstPolygon.push(item);
            };

           //Set path of the second polygon
           secondPolygon.setPath(pathOfFirstPolygon);
```